# Detecting symmetric matrices of the form (low-rank + diagonal matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\Sigma$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix of dimensions $n \times n$. Is there a numerically robust way of checking whether it can be decomposed as $\Sigma = \mathcal{D} + v^t.v$ where $v$ has dimensions $r \times n$ with $r < n-1$ and $\mathcal{D}$ is diagonal with positive elements?

So far, given $\Sigma$, I am checking for minimal $k$ for which positive solutions for diagonal matrix of $\mathrm{rank}(\Sigma -\mathcal{D}) = k$ exist.

I have to add, that even when the solution does exist, it may be non-unique.

Example:

$$
\Sigma = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 6 & 6 & 7 & 0 \\
 6 & 11 & 12 & -3 \\
 7 & 12 & 20 & -6 \\
 0 & -3 & -6 & 9 \\
\end{array} 
\right) \, \text{ where } \mathcal{D} = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right) \text{  and  }
v^t = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 1 \\
 3 & 0 \\
 4 & -1 \\
 -1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$\Sigma$ admits a different representation as well, in fact it is one of 1-parametric family:

$$
 \mathcal{D} = \mathrm{diag}\left(\frac{31}{39}, \frac{403}{203}, \frac{79}{29}, \frac{84}{19} \right) \text{ and } v^t = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 679 \\
 -78 & 696 \\
 -156 & 812 \\
 97 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \cdot \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sqrt{2522} & 0 \\
 0 & 2 \sqrt{19691} \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1}
$$

I have two questions. Why is there a parametric family of solutions ? Can a solution be found by methods of linear algebra ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you accept the numerical accuracy around the order of $[10^{-14},10^{-10}]$, then the following Linear Matrix Inequality solution is robust:

I have tried to solve the related problem : Finding a diagonal matrix $D\succ 0$ such that $$S:=\Sigma-D \succeq 0,\quad \ \operatorname{rank}(S)\leq n-2$$ Rank constraints are always problematic (non-convex) since going up (increasing the rank) is easy but going down is typically very hard (Since the rank of a matrix  is upper semi-continuous..)

Anyway, I have set up a simple LMI problem with a diagonal matrix $D$ as follows
$$ \min_{\displaystyle\substack{ D\succ 0,\\S\succeq 0}} \ \  \operatorname{tr(S)}$$
In other words, I simply minimized the sum of the eigenvalues of $S$, hoping that some of them will come quite close to zero. And much to my surprise, (except a few cases ended up with one, so far) two of them usually turned out to be arbitrarily close to zero. This is also equivalent to maximizing entries of $D$ while keeping the positive semi-definiteness of $S$.

If you have MATLAB and Robust Control Toolbox you can test it for yourself with the following code ([any LMI solver would do](http://users.isy.liu.se/johanl/yalmip/pmwiki.php?n=Main.WhatIsYALMIP)):

```
%Generate some pos def matrix
n = 5;
Sr = rand(n);
Sr = 2*(Sr+Sr');
Sr = 2.5*max(abs(eig(Sr)))*eye(n)+Sr;
% Uncomment the next line for the particular matrix in the question
%Sr = [6 6 7 0;6 11 12 -3;7 12 20 -6;0 -3 -6 9]; n=4;

%Declare LMIs
setlmis([])
D=lmivar(1,[ones(n,1) zeros(n,1)]);
lmiterm([1 1 1 D],1,1);
lmiterm([-1 1 1 0],Sr);
lmis = getlmis;
c = mat2dec(lmis,-eye(n))
[cop,xop] = mincx(lmis,c,[1e-12 200 1e9 20 0]);
Dnum= dec2mat(lmis,xop,D);
disp('The eigenvalues of the difference')
eig(Sr-Dnum)
disp('The rank of the difference')
rank(Sr-Dnum)
disp('The condition number of the difference')
rcond(Sr-Dnum)
```

But as we can expect $(S_r-D_{num})$ is a full rank matrix bur its condition number is generally around $10^{-14}$.

Finally, I have tried your matrix and ended up with 
$$
D = \begin{pmatrix}
      0.75669            &0            &0            &0\\
            0       &2.1392            &0            &0\\
            0            &0       &2.6752            &0\\
            0            &0            &0       &4.4885
\end{pmatrix}
$$
After making sure that m of the eigenvalues are indeed close to zero, obtaining the low rank variable is simply numerical massaging. (This part can be substantially improved in my opinion)

```
[K,L,M] = svd(Sr-Dnum);
M = M';
m=2; %Select how many eigs are close to zero
K = K(:,1:n-m);
L = L(1:n-2,1:n-m);
M = M(1:n-m,:);
T = K*L*M
disp('The rank of V^T V ' )
rank(T) %indeed n-m
V = K*sqrt(L);
% Testing the result
disp('The error of \Sigma = D - v^T v' )
Sr-Dnum-V*V'
```

Numerical result for your variable $v^t$ (rounded off further by the display)
$$
v^t = 
\begin{pmatrix}
       -1.826       &1.3817\\
      -2.9418      &0.45479\\
      -4.1423    & -0.40799\\
       1.2817    &   1.6938
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We also have a necessary condition by using the orthogonal complement $V_\perp$ of $v^t$: 
$$
V_\perp^T\Sigma V_\perp = V_\perp^T D V_\perp 
$$
And this difference also suffers from numerical errors (around $10^{-12}$. Nevertheless, if you are searching for an quick and dirty approximation, this comes to pretty close. By fiddling with the solution $D_{num}$ (which means manual labor),  you can even obtain exact results.

Regarding the theory, I don't know why the number of eigs that come close to zero is $n-2$ in general but not more. I'll try to come back to this if I have some time later.

I don't think an analytical solution would lead to a direct result since the rank is excessively dependent to matrix entries and it would be really tough(and great of course) to obtain something other than approximations.

Lastly, I did not understand what you meant with $1$-parametric family, so I don't have any comments on that :).